# Facing problems with passing down props in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a hard time passing down props to a component. I want to be able to use that object in `componentDidMount` Method. 
My current setup is i have an `App` component that is passing down an object to a `Main`which passes down that object as props to a `TicketTable` Component.

This is my App component

```
 export default class App extends Component {


constructor(props) { 
super(props);
this.state= { 
  keycloak: null,
  authenticated: false,
  user : {}, role: ''
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
    keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
        this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated});
        // this.state.keycloak.loadUserInfo().success(user => this.setState({user}));
    }).catch(err=>console.log("ERROR", err));
 }
   render() {
return (

  <div>
      <Main keycloak={this.state.keycloak}/>
```

This is my Main component

```
export default class Main extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
 this.state={keycloak:''}
}

componentDidMount(){
  console.log("MAIN PROPS",this.props);
}


}
 render() {
     return (
       <div>
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" render={(props)=><TicketTable 
  {...props} keycloak={this.state.keycloak}/>}/>
```

I want to to able to use the `Keycloak` object in my `TicketTable` component.

Thank you. 
Ps: I want to able to do that without the need of using a state management framework like `redux`

Comment: *"I want to to able to use the Keycloak object in my TicketTable component."* What specific problem are you having doing that? (Other than that the prop is `keycloak`, not `Keycloak`.) You seem to be passing the prop to TicketTable. If you're having trouble using it in TicketTable, why not show us TicketTable? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keycloak` prop that you are passing to your `TicketTable` component is actually empty because you are passing the *state* of the `Route` component as the prop and not the one which you got from `App` component.

So make this change and I think it should work:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(props)=><TicketTable 
{...props} keycloak={this.props.keycloak}/>}/>
```

Comment: And he/she should probably get rid of the `this.state = {keycloak: ''};` in the `Main` constructor.

Comment: Agreed. But since OP also puts in the `keycloak={this.state.keycloak}`, the original prop that the spread operator will be overridden with this statement. So maybe the OP should totally omit this statement completely (which is better IMO) and stick with `{...props}`

Comment: `props` and `this.props` are different. `props` is a function argument in the arrow function creating `TicketTable` (in the `render` prop on `Route`). `this.props` is the `Main` component's props.

Comment: I have changed the Route and deleted the <code>this.state= {keycloak:''}</code> And i'm getting null. After trying to <code>console.log</code> the props in both <code>Main</code and <code>TicketTable</code>. I see that the <code>componentDidMount</code> of <code>TicketTable</code> is running before <code>Main</code> which should not be the case. Any idea why is that?